# access to filter property from the appender

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-appender, log4net-filter

Given a class extending *FilterSkeleton* with a property name *MyName* and an appender extending *ApenderSkeleton*

is it possible to get the *MyName* property of the filter which accepted this message while in the Append method of the appender ?

```
protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
{
     //sudo
     var somename = acceptedfilter.MyName;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `FilterEvent` method to save the filter that accepts the message, and then retrieve it in `Append`:

```
public class FilteredAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
    private IFilter filter;

    protected override bool FilterEvent(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        IFilter f = this.FilterHead;

        while (f != null)
        {
            if (f.Decide(loggingEvent) == FilterDecision.Accept)
            {
                filter = f; // Set the filter field
                break;
            }

            f = f.Next;
        }

        return base.FilterEvent(loggingEvent);
    }

    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        NamedFilter acceptedfilter = filter as NamedFilter;            

        if (acceptedfilter!= null)
        {
              var somename = acceptedfilter.MyName;
              // etc
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you.  ( not sure what i was "smoking" when i saw that method the first time :)  )